# Weka- Importing .csv file error into Weka

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-science, weka, unsupervised-learning

I'm using Weka to implement a unsupervised algorithms like LOF to detect outliers within a given dataset but of course the dataset has to contain binary attributes as LOF is dependent on this (according Weka compatibility information) and it does (0,0,1,0,1). However, when I try to import the dataset from the preprocessing section on Weka I get back an error outling this:

File: C:\Users\JohnDoe\Downloads\labelled_Dataset.csv

Reason: index 13 out of bounds for length 13 Problem encountered on line: 293

Does anyone here have any ideas on how to overcome this, I've never encountered this error and a google search doesn't particularly help in this context too as it comes back with different results. I've been at this for 4 days, any advice will be taken into consideration.

Comment: Have you checked how many cells that line has? Not sure whether this line no is 1-based or 0-based. It pays to check the lines around the referenced one.

Comment: It's mutli-valued nominal dataset that has binary attributes.  the entire dataset is full of commas . It's a multi valued nominal (categorical/labelled) datadset alongside binary attributes (0,1,0,0,1) purely for anomaly detection use cases. I genuinely have no clue at this point on why such simple task like importing in Weka is not working :/ .

Comment: After some research, rhe error message is saying that it's trying to load 14 or more elements from a line with only 13 elements in it. I've used notepad ++ to replace all the "". I may be giving up at this point now tbh and go with the KNN algoritm (supervised approach) and just assume outliers which isn't very pratical for this kind of use case context.

Comment: The CSVLoader in Weka uses its own standard, which differs a bit from the other variants out there. You could try the [common-csv](https://github.com/fracpete/common-csv-weka-package) or just switch to using the Weka Investigator that comes with [ADAMS](https://adams.cms.waikato.ac.nz/download/snapshot/) (use the adams-ml-app snapshot).

Comment: There seems to be quite a bit going on with the website you are directing me too. I did notice whlist looking at the video there is dedicated VM for the ADAMS investigator but I can't seem to find that anywhere. Never mind, I think I've found the release you've published (congrats on that) https://adams.cms.waikato.ac.nz/download/21-12-0/.

Comment: Releases only occur once in a while as they are time consuming. Snapshots are daily builds, incorporating the latest bugfixes and features.

Comment: Thanks! Please post an answer to your question on how you solved. That will help other people.

Comment: Update finally managed to get it working!!!!!! using Weka.Thank you for your continuous help man. People like you are needed within our community (edit/grammer).

Comment: Will do, need to this dissertation out the way first xD xD. Took me nine days to fix, feels bad man.